# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: FIFOQueue '_0_string_input_producer' is closed

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow version 1.2.1, using windows 10-64 bit, python 3.5, when running my codes encountered this error as:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Starting standard services.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path ../train_log\model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting queue runners.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step None.
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class **'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError'>, FIFOQueue '_0_string_input_producer' is closed.**
     [[Node: string_input_producer/string_input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](string_input_producer, string_input_producer/limit_epochs)]]
**INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError'>, FIFOQueue '_0_string_input_producer' is closed.**
     [[Node: string_input_producer/string_input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](string_input_producer, string_input_producer/limit_epochs)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/study/Lab/python/pycharm/hat_or_not/train/train_CNN.py", line 166, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "D:/study/Lab/python/pycharm/hat_or_not/train/train_CNN.py", line 162, in main
    run_train_model()
  File "D:/study/Lab/python/pycharm/hat_or_not/train/train_CNN.py", line 157, in run_train_model
    coord.join(threads=threads)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1063, in _single_operation_run
    target_list_as_strings, status, None)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: FIFOQueue '_0_string_input_producer' is closed.**
     [[Node: string_input_producer/string_input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](string_input_producer, string_input_producer/limit_epochs)]]
```

note the error message says only:

```
CancelledError:FIFOQueue '_0_string_input_producer' is closed.
```

I know there is other OutOfRangeError which tells you the producer ends correctly:

```
OutOfRangeError : FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, cu rrent size 0)
```

which is not the issue I encountered.
so, what's the big idea? Any help would be highly appreciated! 
my demo codes go like:

```
**records_path_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(records_path, seed=123,num_epochs=num_epochs,name="string_input_producer")**
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(records_path_queue,name="serialized_example")
......
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1.0 / 255) - 0.5
label = tf.cast(features["label"], tf.int32)
**images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, name="shuffle_bath",capacity=200 + 2 * batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True,min_after_dequeue=100)**
......
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                           tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        .......
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as e:
    print("Finished training for %d epochs %d steps" % (Flags.num_epochs, global_step))
finally:
   coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads=threads)
sess.close()
```

Comment: Why not use MonitoredSession? It correctly keeps track of queue runners and whatnot for you. The queue can be closed if something else caused your training coordinator to want to exit. Could there have been an error in another thread?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos thanks, seems tf.train.Supervisor() is now  deprecated？ you think the MonitoredSession will handle this error well?

Comment: Supervisor can be replaced with MonitoredSession for better performance and debugability (no random background threads). It might surface your exception more easily. I still think you should examine all stack traces to figure out why the queue is being closed.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Hello, I studied the [MonitoredSession API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredSession), which seems  MonitoredSession is for Distributed TensorFlow?

Comment: It can also be used locally as a supervisor replacement.